# Load javascript code after loading code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a web site released at facebook platform, i am using C# .Net 2008, the problem is that i am loading an array elements from code behind in javascript arary and i am loading elelment element using the following javascript code :

```
ArList = new Array('<%=ListOfWords[0]%>','<%=ListOfWords[1]%>','<%=ListOfWords[2]%>','<%=ListOfWords[2]%>');
```

the problem that when i call an element from the array as follows :

```
document.getElementById("WordDiv").innerHTML = ArList [0];
```

The element is not set with the value inspite the array in the code behind has values and i don't know why the value of the array element is not set ? and in some cases i found it loaded with value and everything go right so may be it's a problem in rendering so the value of code behind is not seen in client side ? or where is the problem come ?
and when i traced the application in IE i found the status bar report a javascript error then disappered and say done and when the yellow allert appears in the status bar i have clicked it and noticed the message says : object expected.

The problem now is that in onload event of the body tag i call a function in the javascript that intialize the javascript array with values from code behind array and the problem is that in some cases the function is not entered as i traced it by putting an alert in the begining of the function and i found that when the javascript array is not filled the code of the function is not entered as the alert is not showed so i don't know how to force the DOM to enter this function which i call it in the  tag here sample of the code:
javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head runat="server">         
     </head>
     <body onload="IntializeArr(); return false;">
     <form id="form1" runat="server" >
     ..........Some Controls...............
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    var TList;
    var BList;
       function IntializeArr()
     {       
        TList = new Array('<%=ListofT[0]%>','<%=ListofT[1]%>','<%=ListofT[2]%>','<%=ListofT[3]%>','<%=ListofT[4]%>','<%=ListofT[5]%>','<%=ListofT[6]%>','<%=ListofT[7]%>','<%=ListofT[8]%>','<%=ListofT[9]%>');
        BList = new Array('<%=ListOfB[0]%>','<%=ListOfB[1]%>','<%=ListOfB[2]%>','<%=ListOfB[3]%>','<%=ListOfB[4]%>','<%=ListOfB[5]%>','<%=ListOfB[6]%>','<%=ListOfB[7]%>','<%=ListOfB[8]%>','<%=ListOfB[9]%>');        
     }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

C# Code :

```
public string[] ListOfB = new string[15];
public string[] ListofT = new string[15];
```

And the code behind array is filled from data returned from database and they are filled i have traced them and each time and they are filled and i found that the problem from javascript i don't know if it is from facebook platform or from my code but i think that it is not from my code as the problem that i call a function in the onload of the tag  and the function is not entered and this is the problem so can any one help me please

Hope that i will find a solution as i got depressed

Comment: Don't get depressed, its only code and half the fun of this line of work is getting there no matter how frustrating it gets. In the end the reward of defeating a tough problem should be good enough.

Comment: i got depressed because it took too much time and i got bored and don't know the solution and this problem broke down all my work and cause to me many troubles so i need help urgently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IntializeArr() function is not being called, it is most likely a javascript error in the page, and most likely caused by some invalid javascript characters in the ListofT or ListofB arrays.

You should be escaping any single quotes or newlines.

Easiest way to check is to just "view source" in the browser once the page has loaded. Look down to your script and find what values were put it and you should see if there were any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ListofWords[0] contains an apostrophe?

Comment: No it doesn't contains any apostrophs but may be and rarely contains double cotation (") and i think that this is not the reason but i think that it's something related to rendering or something in javascript or in facebook platform

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Facebook platform, so I'm afraid I cannot help you there. I'd suggest, if at all possible, to reduce the problem to it's core, and if at all possible, try to share the code.

Comment: i am accessing DB and get data in the load of the page and then looping the returned DataTable and get it's records in an array and then in the javascript i got this elements of the array as it is fixed array so i got each element as i described in the post and then sometimes i found the javascript variable got the array elements and sometimes not got it may be this because the DB access?

Comment: Without a more detailed error report or more code examples, or code-output, it's impossible to say what the issue is.

Comment: See the new editting of the post and it will include more details
and i hope that i will find a solution in the end

Comment: and when i removed  the silver tag that call the code behind code it works well but the javascript array is not filled so the problem now is in filling the javascript array from code behind array and when i used Page.RegisterArrayDeclaration() it doesn't work also and javascript not feel with array registred from code behind

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputting the JS array creation to the page inside `<script>` tags?

You have to emit that javascript so that the browser can run it - then ArList will be available on the page to other javascript.

Comment: yes i am putting it inside <script> tag, as i decalred the array inside the <script> and using it inside also the <script> tag and i can't understand what do u mean else?

Answer (score 0):

Agree, more code example is needed.

Usually I solve something like this by using Sys.Application.add_init() or $(document).ready(). However there are other possible solutions. Use an AJAX request to get the array. Or something like:

```
function setInnerHtml() {
    if (typeof(ArList) != "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("WordDiv").innerHTML = ArList[0];
    } else {
        setTimeout("setInnerHtml()", 40);
    }
}
```